# How to post to users' facebook wall even if they are not on my app web page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an application that can post to user's wall when they visit my application page. But there are too much apps that are posting to users' wall even if users are not visiting their application (Users only visit once and give required permissions).  I want to post to users' wall when they are offline and far away from Facebook.
Can you suggest how can I do that.

I am using PHP sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a long lived token for 2 months

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: If I get long lived token then how to publish to users wall that is not on my app page?

Comment: @mwaseema I'm not sure I understand what you are saying

Comment: @mwaseema you have to use the saved long lived access token and use the same to post on the respective users wall normally, as you would have done when user was present, by sending `HTTP POST` to `/userid/feed`. Same documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)